# JavaScript radio button issues

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I need to make image library from 5 images. Images must be selected and shown by one through different radio buttons. No submit buttons are allowed. So until now I wrote code for image output by image name. The default number is 0=first image. But issue is that when I click on different radio button, my function did not output new number and did not make radio checked="checked".

My function:

```
function radiocheck()
{
    for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (document.forms[1].elements[i].checked=="true")
        {
            var whichISchecked = document.forms[1].elements[i].value;

            for (var z=0; z<i; z++)
            {
                document.forms[1].elements[z].checked="unchecked";
            }
            for (var z=i; z<5; z++)
            {
                document.forms[1].elements[z].checked="unchecked";
            }
        }
        else 
        {   
            document.forms[1].elements[0].checked="checked";
            var whichISchecked = document.forms[1].elements[0].value;
        }
    }
    return whichISchecked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are supposed to handle checking and unchecking by themselves. Consider this code (also at http://jsfiddle.net/87wkC/1/)

```
<form id="f">
<input type="radio" value="1" onclick="getValue(this.value)" name="field1">A<br>
<input type="radio" value="2" onclick="getValue(this.value)" name="field1">B<br>
<input type="radio" value="3" onclick="getValue(this.value)" name="field1">C<br>
<input type="radio" value="4" onclick="getValue(this.value)" name="field1">D<br>
<input type="radio" value="5" onclick="getValue(this.value)" name="field1">E<br>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
function getValue(a){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a
}
</script>
```

Clicking an option button clears the others (that's handled by giving them all the same `name`) and makes its value available — the function outputs that below the list.

Comment: Thank you alot. But now I get only output value and dont know how to use it for selecting image.

Comment: Well, that isn't in your question. My function `getValue()` gives the same result as your function `radiocheck()`. How are using that result?

Comment: now it works. i did every images value = "<img src=/name.jpg>"  Now i got image as output in same window screen when radio button is checked. And it is possible to to manipulate width or height from this point? Can value tags have variables for manipulating width and height?

Comment: The scope of the question is creeping and SO doesn't handle it well. Try something (you could pass several variables to the handler function and return an object, for example). If you don't get anywhere, ask another question about what you did. And if *this* answer is ok for this question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

change unchecked string to false

```
document.forms[1].elements[z].checked="unchecked";
```

to

```
document.forms[1].elements[z].checked=false;
```

also

```
document.forms[1].elements[i].checked=="true"
```

shouldn't it be like

```
document.forms[1].elements[i].checked===true
```

Answer (score 0):

a)  Use jQuery, things will be MUCH easier

b)  You should be checking

```
checked == true
```

and not

```
checked == "true"
```

and

```
checked = "checked"
```

won't do anything, it's only a true/false value

Comment: ok did as you said. Now i cant select another radio button its always default = 0;

Comment: that <input type="radio" onclick="function()"> doesint work at all.